# WCF post method implementation

Tags: c#, sql, ajax, wcf, post

I have a WCF service which is connected to an sql server database which is called from a mobile application. I have the following method which helps create bookings.

```
public void CreateBooking(Booking booking)
    {
        Booking newbooking = new Booking();
        sql = new SqlConnection("Data Source=comp;Initial Catalog=BookingDB;Integrated Security=True");
        sql.Open();

        string command =
            ("INSERT INTO Bookings( BookingName, BookingStart, BookingEnd, RoomID ) " +
             "VALUES ("
                + "'" + booking.BookingName + "'" + ", "   
                + "'" + booking.BookingStart  + "'" + ", " 
                + "'" + booking.BookingEnd + "'" + ", "
                        + booking.RoomID + ")");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, sql);                
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();            
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        sql.Close();
    }
```

Markup:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="BookingServices.BookingService" CodeBehind="BookingService.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <!--<authentication mode="None"/>-->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="RoomBookingServices.RoomBookingService" behaviorConfiguration="RoomBookingServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="http://192.168.0.4:6321/RoomBookingServices/RoomBookingService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="RoomBookingServices.IRoomBookingService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior">
      <identity>
        <servicePrincipalName value=""/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RoomBookingServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  
      Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
       </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
         <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"></binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->
<!--<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RoomBookingDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HAL;initial catalog=RoomBookingDatabase;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="RoomBookingDatabaseEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RoomBookingDB.csdl|res://*/RoomBookingDB.ssdl|res://*/RoomBookingDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HAL;initial catalog=RoomBookingDatabase;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Interface:

```
[OperationContract(Name="postmethod")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "postmethod/new")]

    void CreateBooking(Booking booking); 
}
```

Booking class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Booking
{
    [DataMember]
    public int BookingID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BookingName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime BookingStart { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime BookingEnd { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int RoomID { get; set; }

}
```

However, whenever I call the method I am getting a 405 error. My question is, is the method above causing the error or is it something in the connection end of things? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your configuration file and the interface of the service. Is your service RESTful or SOAP service

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I have uploaded the config and interface into the main question. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the skeleton for your Booking class as well if that is not a problem

Comment: As an aside, you really need to look at parameterize your SQL query - or you run the risk of allowing SQL injection attacks.  Simple example here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: Update with booking class and markup of svc also.

Comment: Also what is your hosting mechanism

Comment: Hi Rajesh, my hosting mechanism is IIS 7, where I have the wcf deployed as an application.

Comment: Also make sure that you have set the app pool to .NET 4 in IIS.

Comment: Usign WCF tracing often helps to narrow down the error. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx for how to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried the above scenario and with few changes i got it working as shown below:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "postmethod/new")]
        Booking CreateBooking(Booking booking);
```

You can remove the WrappedRequest setting as you just have only 1 param.

When i perform a POST from Fidder with the below request i get a successful response:

```
POST http://localhost/SampleApp/Service1.svc/postmethod/new HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 144
Expect: 100-continue

{"BookingEnd":"\/Date(1332420656202+0000)\/","BookingID":1,"BookingName":"client sent","BookingStart":"\/Date(1332334256202+0000)\/","RoomID":2}
```

You can remove the name attribute in the OperationContract as well. If you are hosting in IIS then the address can be empty as the address is assigned by IIS.

Answer (score 3):

When you are hosting a WCF service in IIS the `address` attribute is inferred from the location to the `.svc` file as hosted in IIS so it should either empty or a relative address:

```
<service name="RoomBookingServices.RoomBookingService" behaviorConfiguration="RoomBookingServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint 
        address="" 
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
        contract="RoomBookingServices.IRoomBookingService" 
        behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior">
    </endpoint>
</service>
```

The base address will be provided by IIS and the site where you are hosting your application under. So it will point to the location of the `RoomBookingService.svc` file as hosted in IIS.

Also when I look at the following code:

```
string command =
        ("INSERT INTO Bookings( BookingName, BookingStart, BookingEnd, RoomID ) " +
         "VALUES ("
            + "'" + booking.BookingName + "'" + ", "   
            + "'" + booking.BookingStart  + "'" + ", " 
            + "'" + booking.BookingEnd + "'" + ", "
                    + booking.RoomID + ")");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, sql);
```

my eyes start to bleed. You should absolutely never write any code like that. Always use parametrized queries when dealing with SQL. Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

So:

```
public void CreateBooking(Booking booking)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=comp;Initial Catalog=BookingDB;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = 
        @"INSERT INTO 
          Bookings( BookingName, BookingStart, BookingEnd, RoomID ) 
          VALUES ( @BookingName, @BookingStart, @BookingEnd, @RoomID )";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingName", booking.BookingName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingStart", booking.BookingStart);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingEnd", booking.BookingEnd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomID", booking.RoomID);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And now you could invoke this service. For example using jQuery AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/RoomBookingService.svc/postmethod/new',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 
        booking: {
            BookingID: 1,
            BookingName: 'bn',
            BookingStart: '/Date(1232739449000+0000)/',
            BookingEnd: '/Date(1232776449000+0000)/',
            RoomID: 2
        }
    }),
    success: function (result) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Darin, thanks for the tip. This is all new to me so its good to learn about these things! Thanks.